# PhantomJS Cookies Retain and Reuse On Subsequent Request

Tags: cookies, phantomjs

I have just installed `phantom.js` and am trying to use it now.

I am trying to fetch the contents of a website, however I need to indicate that I agree to their privacy policy before continuing.

My current code is below:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
lastName = "T";
firstName = "N";
mmddyyyyS = "12/03/2016";
mmddyyyyE = "12/04/2016";
page.open("http://example.com/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis");
page.open("http://example.com/casesearch/inquirySearch.jis?lastName="+lastName+"company=N&firstName="+firstName+"&filingStart="+mmddyyyyS+"&filingEnd="+mmddyyyyE, function(status) {  
    if ( status === "success" ) {
        if (page.injectJs("jquery.min.js")&&page.injectJs("moment.min.js")) {
            var h1 = page.evaluate(function() {
                return $("h1:eq(0)").css({fontSize: 10, color: "red"}).text();
            });
            console.log(h1);
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log("error");
    }
});
phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  var msgStack = ['PHANTOM ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
  phantom.exit(1);
};
```

I always get an error, from `console.log("error")`. I believe this is because I am making the first request that indicates I accept their terms, but the cookie I would normally get in the browser after this submission is not being stored for the subsequent (second) `page.open` request. I have seen in the documentation `addCookie()` and `page.cookies` but nothing about chaining requests so that the cookie attained on one page is used in the request for the second page.

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any network requests are asynchronous in PhantomJS, so the second `page.open` is started before the first could finish, that's why an error is issued.

```
page.open("http://example.com/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis", function(){

    // this block is executed after the first page is opened
    page.open("http://example.com/casesearch/inquirySearch.jis?lastName="+lastName+"company=N&firstName="+firstName+"&filingStart="+mmddyyyyS+"&filingEnd="+mmddyyyyE, function(status) {

        // after the second page is opened

    })
});
```

Also note that PhantomJS can retain cookies from previous requests for future use when run with command-line argument `--cookies-file`

```
/path/to/phantomjs --cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt /path/to/script.js
```